# How to pass complete row data from csv iterated Scenario Outline to other feature?

Tags: karate

I want to pass whole row data to other feature from scenario outline. Below is my code sample.

```
Scenario Outline: Calling scenario
 * def data = call read('CalledFeature.feature') #Here want to pass the complete row data from the iterated csv

Examples:
| sample.csv |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire row will be present in a built-in variable called `__row`. Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements